# Repeatedly execute same code before/after statements/code blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am filtering some data in a `pandas.DataFrame` and want to track the rows I loose. So basically, I want to

```
df = pandas.read_csv(...)
n1 = df.shape[0]
df = ...  # some logic that might reduce the number of rows
print(f'Lost {n1 - df.shape[0]} rows')
```

Now there are multiple of these filter steps, and the code before/after it is always the same. So I am looking for a way to abstract that away.

Of course the first thing that comes into mind are decorators - however, I don't like the idea of creating a bunch of functions with just one LOC.

What I came up with are context managers:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def rows_lost(df):
    try:
        n1 = df.shape[0]
        yield df
    finally:
         print(f'Lost {n1 - df.shape[0]} rows')
```

And then:

```
with rows_lost(df) as df:
    df = ...
```

I am wondering whether there is a better solution to this?

**Edit**:
I just realized that the context manager approach does not work, if a filter step returns a new object (which is the default for pandas Dataframes). It only works when the objects are modified "in place".

Comment: What do you have against decorators? They are perfect for exactly this.

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yes, I know. And no, I don't have anything against decorators. I just don't want to create a function for every filter step - which typically are just 1-3 LOC.

Comment: Yes that concern just came to me. I think I have found a solution to that. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a "wrapper-function" that wraps the filter you specify:

```
def filter1(arg):
    return arg+1

def filter2(arg):
    return arg*2

def wrap_filter(arg, filter_func):
    print('calculating with argument', arg)
    result = filter_func(arg)
    print('result', result)
    return result

wrap_filter(5, filter1)
wrap_filter(5, filter2)
```

The only thing that this improves on using a decorator is that you can choose to call the filter without the wrapper...

Comment: Thanks. I also thought of something like this. I discarded it because the filters are mostly methods of the `df` object (a pandas DataFrame), and more importantly, if the filter is more than 1 LOC/operation, I would need to define a function again.

Comment: This method works even better for predefined functions. This way you do not need to redefine them with a decorator added...

Comment: Yes, you are right, this works quite well. Can use ``lambda`` if the operation is not a callable (e.g. a slice). The context manager approach turned out to have a caveat also (see edit).